# Parameterization of Gamma Distribution

Tags: gamma-distribution, parameterization

I have come upon different parameterizations of the Gamma Distribution, but not with regard to shape-scale or shape-rate. It is rather about the sign in the exponent. 
Wolfram lists the pdf as being proportional to $$x^{a-1} \exp{-\frac{x}{b}}$$ https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GammaDistribution.html
However, I saw some papers where the minus sign is missing such that,
$$x^{a-1}\exp{\frac{x}{b}}$$ From my understanding, both parameters $a$ and $b$ have to be positive so this must make some kind of difference. Do I have some error in reasoning here?

Edit: Excerpt from a paper
[image: formula]

Comment: Could you provide a reference where you actually saw the formula *without* minus sign..?

Comment: Sure, for instance: Jumps in Equity Index Returns Before and During the Recent Financial Crisis: A Bayesian Analysis (2016, by Kou, Yu and Zhong) on p. 5 in the footnote

Comment: I added a screenshot for clarification.

Comment: This formulation is simply **wrong**. Have you tried plotting this function..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is clearly a typo in the paper. You can verify that by seeing that the form of the pdf they present, does not integrate to something finite.

$$x^{\alpha - 1} e^{x/\beta} \to 0 \text{ as } x \to 0$$

$$x^{\alpha - 1} e^{x/\beta} \to \infty \text{ as } x \to \infty.$$

Thus, the pdf integrates to infinity. You can see that in wolfram alpha [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x%5E%7B5-1%7D+exp(x%2F2)+from++x+%3D+0+to+x+%3D+infty).

Thus, the integral diverges, and the pdf presented is not a valid pdf.

Comment: Hey, the paper is 2016, so there is still time to correct the typo! (Or, given the paper title, could this be a sly way to seed the *next* financial crisis by misleading the next gen of quants?)

Comment: Okay, thank you very much! Astonishingly, I found another paper with the exact same typo but from 2008.